# Worker threads using 'node-worker-threads-pool' – can't find class at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, multithreading, es6-modules, node-worker-threads

I may be demonstrating my deep, deep ignorance of threading in node, but this is my first attempt at using worker threads, and the [documentation says](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads) I ought to use a worker pool.

So here we are. I am using the `node-worker-threads-pool` package. My app will be training several dozen ML models simultaneously using TensorFlow.

The following TypeScript code falls over at runtime, although it transpiles fine:

```
trainModels = async () => {
   const modelIds: string[] = getModelId();

   for await (const modelId of modelIds) {
      this.dynamicPool.exec({
         task: id => {
            const predictor = new Predictor(id, []);
            // ...do such-and-such
         },
         param: modelId,
      });
   }
};
```

The runtime complains:

> ReferenceError [Error]: Predictor is not defined

So it can't find it. Accessing the class elsewhere in the code is fine; but not within a thread.

I"m guessing this is threading 101 in node. How do I get around this? Perhaps I can construct the class and then create the thread within that class instead? What is the pattern?

Comment: Uh. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool: "*Notice: If task is a function, you can NOT access variables defined outside the task function! If you do want to use external data, use workerData to pass some cloneable data.*" So no, this has nothing to do with threading, and rather how this particular package chose to serialise code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've done this. Seems to be happier:

```
constructor(private pairNames: string[], private data: ModelData[]) {
   for (const pairName of pairNames) {
      this.dynamicPool.exec({
         task: this.execTask,
         param: pairName,
      });
   }
   console.log(`In Predictor constructor`);
}

private execTask = async (pairName: string) => {
   console.log(`In Predictor execTask for ${pairName}`);
};
```